# Batch file - For loop incrementation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem with my loop, i don't know how to use the %%A to edit my variable.

For example, i want to set IPAdresse like that:

- 10.98.1.10
- 10.98.2.10
- 10.98.3.10 ...

Here the code :

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,200) DO (

set "IPAdresse=10.98.%%A.10"

---> do something

)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very poor description of your problem , but looks like you need delayed expansion - https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: I just edit my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,200) DO (
    set "IPAdresse=10.98.%%A.10"
    Call :PingIP !IPAdresse!
)
pause
exit /b
:PingIP 
echo Pinging %1
Ping %1
```

Comment: Put an Exit/b after the pause and not at the end :PingIP

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,200) DO ping 10.98.%%A.10
```

Is the generic way of doing this.